# error trying to install font awesome via npm

Tags: npm, font-awesome, react-font-awesome

When I am installing font awesome via terminal (npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core) as recommended in the docs, I'm getting this error:

```
npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! Incorrect or missing password.
npm ERR! If you were trying to login, change your password, create an
npm ERR! authentication token or enable two-factor authentication then
npm ERR! that means you likely typed your password in incorrectly.
npm ERR! Please try again, or recover your password at:
npm ERR!     https://www.npmjs.com/forgot
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you were doing some other operation then your saved credentials are
npm ERR! probably out of date. To correct this please try logging in again with:
npm ERR!     npm login
```

Installing other dependecies, e.g. "npm i nanoid" works like a charm. Any ideas?
Regards!

installing dependencies via npm without error message

Answer (score 1):

I solved the error myself. You need to delete this line from your .npmrc file

`@fortawesome:registry=https://npm.fontawesome.com/`

Solution from here: https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/13794

Comment: This worked with a twist for me. Removing the suggested line allowed me to download the `free-` Font Awesome packages but not the `pro-`. So I restored the line, following the guide below to do so. Afterward, I re-ran the `npm i` commands to download the `pro-` packages, and all went well.

... And here's the other resource I used to troubleshoot the issue: https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/setup/packages#project-specific-using-configuration-files-recommended